# Prove or disprove $\frac{(x+n)!}{(x!)\text{lcm}(x+1, \dots, x+n)} < (n-1)!$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, solution-verification, factorial, gcd-and-lcm

Is it correct that for any  positive integers $x,n$, that $\frac{(x+n)!}{(x!)\text{lcm}(x+1, \dots, x+n)} < (n-1)!$ where lcm is the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).

I ask because I find this relationship very interesting but I haven't seen it stated in this form.

I have seen a related [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) that:

$$\frac{\text{lcm}(x,x+1, \dots, x+n)}{x} \ge {{x+n}\choose{n}} = \frac{(x+n)!}{x!n!} $$

Which rearranges to this:

$$\frac{n!}{x} \ge \frac{(x+n)!}{(x!)\text{lcm}(x,x+1,\dots,x+n)}$$

Or even closer:

$$n! \ge \frac{(x+n)!}{((x-1)!)\text{lcm}(x,x+1,\dots,x+n)}$$

So that:

$$n! \ge \frac{(x+n)!}{(x!)\text{lcm}(x+1,\dots,x+n)}$$

This appears to me to be a stronger result than the one I am asking about. I am not clear how to derive my result from this stronger result.

On the other hand, I am able to justify my result independently of this equation.  Here's my argument:

(1)  Let $f_n(x) = \dfrac{(x+n)!}{(x!)\text{lcm}(x+1, \dots, x+n)}$

(2)  No prime greater than $n-1$ divides $f_n(x)$ since:

> Assume that a prime $p>n$ divides $x+c$ and $x+d$ with $0 < c < d \le n$.  It follows that $p | (x+d - x+c) = d - c < n$ which is impossible.

(3) For each prime $p < n$ that divides $f_n(x)$, we can use [Legendre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) to get this result (since we are dividing by the least common multiple):

$$v_p\left(\frac{(x+n)!}{(x!)\text{lcm}(x+1,\dots,x+n)}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}-1\right\rfloor < v_p((n-1)!) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{p^i}\right\rfloor$$

where $v_p(x)$ is the largest power of $p$ that is less than or equal to $x$

Note: It is based on $n$ instead of $x+n$ because $p^t$ is necessarily less than $n$

Is my reasoning correct?  Is there a straight forward way to derive this result from the first equation?  Is the argument that I present using Legendre's Formula valid?  If valid, can it be improved or simplified?  If not valid, what was my mistake?

Comment: A minor point is you state $n! \ge \frac{(x+n)!}{(x!)\operatorname{lcm}(x+1,\dots,x+n)}$ is a "... stronger result than the one I am asking about". Actually, since your left side is $(n-1)!$, which is considerably smaller than $n!$, the other result is actually a *weaker* result since your result (at least for $n \ge 3$) implies the other one, or alternatively, note the other result doesn't imply yours.

Comment: FYI, basically the same question as yours, except with different notation and using $\le$ instead of $\lt$ in the inequality, was asked about $2$ days ago at [An inequality about the product of continuous Integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4034610/602049). For some reason, though, the OP deleted it a few hours after asking it, with it having $2$ upvotes, no downvotes, no comments and no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3687911/602049) from [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967/mathlove) gives several equality counter-examples to your conjecture. I prove below that changing your conjecture's $\lt$ to $\le$ is sufficient to make it correct.

As for your proof, the left part of your expression in step $(3)$ is

$$v_p\left(\frac{(x+n)!}{(x!)\operatorname{lcm}(x+1,\dots,x+n)}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}-1\right\rfloor \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

With $i$ large enough so $p^i \gt n$, then $-1 \lt \frac{n}{p_i} - 1 \lt 0 \implies \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}-1\right\rfloor = -1$. Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}-1\right\rfloor = -\infty$. Also, I believe your note of "It is based on $n$ instead of $x+n$ because $p^t$ is necessarily less than $n$" means you tried using

$$\left\lfloor\frac{x+n}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{x}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

However, even with your restriction, this is not always true. For example, with $t = i = 1$, $p = 3$, $n = 4$ and $x = 5$, the left side of \eqref{eq2A} becomes $\left\lfloor\frac{9}{3}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{5}{3}\right\rfloor = 3 - 1 = 2$ while the right side becomes $\left\lfloor\frac{4}{3}\right\rfloor = 1$.

In addition, I assume the $-1$ term on the right side in \eqref{eq1A} comes from the $\operatorname{lcm}$ having its exponent of $p$ be the maximum among the prime factorizations of the integers in $[x+1,x+n]$. However, the $-1$ term should only be used up to that exponent, not to $\infty$, since this causes the sum in \eqref{eq1A} to go to $-\infty$, as I explained earlier.

---

I don't see any direct way to use what you're trying to do. Instead, your conjecture's $\leq$ version can be proven using an equivalent form of your inequality,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{(x + n)!}{(x!)\operatorname{lcm}(x + 1, \, \ldots, \, x + n)} & \le (n-1)! \iff \\
\frac{(x + n)!}{(x!)(n-1)!} & \le \operatorname{lcm}(x + 1, \, \ldots, \, x + n) \iff \\
n\left(\frac{(x + n)!}{(x!)(n!)}\right) & \le \operatorname{lcm}(x + 1, \, \ldots, \, x + n) \iff \\
n\binom{x + n}{n} & \le \operatorname{lcm}(x + 1, \, \dots, \, x + n)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Note this form is related to that in your question [Reasoning about least common multiples and their relationship to binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3694406/602049), and my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3956853/602049) there is also fairly similar to this proof. First, for somewhat simpler algebra, let

$$b = \binom{x + n}{n}, \; c = \operatorname{lcm}(x + 1, \, \dots, \, x + n) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Using the prime factorization exponents based on the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of $\operatorname{lcm}$, and the [$p$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) function, then for any prime $p$, let

$$d = \nu_{p}(n) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

$$e = \nu_{p}(b) \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

$$f = \nu_{p}(c) = \max_{x + 1 \, \le \, i \, \le x + n}(\nu_{p}(i)) \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

By proving

$$d + e \le f \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

for all primes $p$, then \eqref{eq3A} will be true. There are $2$ basic cases to consider:

**Case #$1$:** $e = 0$

Since $[x + 1, x + n]$ is a set of $n$ consecutive integers, they represent a [complete residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system) of integers modulo $n$, so there's a $1 \le i \le n$ where $x + i \equiv 0 \pmod n \implies x + i = kn, \; k \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, for this $i$ and $k$,

$$d = \nu_p(n) \le \nu_p(kn) = \nu_p(x + i) \le f \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

which shows \eqref{eq8A} holds.

**Case #$2$:** $e > 0$

Note [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) states $e$ (as defined in \eqref{eq6A}) is the number of carries when $x$ is added to $n$ in each prime base $p$. Thus, there must be at least one carry in this case.

Define for any integer $y \ge 0$ it's standard base $p$ representation as

$$y = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i p^{i}, \; 0 \le a_i \le p - 1 \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

and the following function to specify the requested digit

$$g(y, i) = a_i \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

Thus, from \eqref{eq5A},

$$g(n, i) = 0 \; \forall \; 0 \le i \le d - 1 \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

i.e., the lowest $d$ digits of $n$ in base $p$ are $0$. This means none of these digits can be involved in a carry when $x$ is added to $n$, so the first possible such digit is $g(n, d)$. Since there's at least one carry, there's a maximum index involved. Let $h \ge d$ be the index of the digit where the highest carry comes from. This means the next higher index digit is increased by $1$, i.e.,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& g(n + x, h + 1) = g(n, h + 1) + g(x, h + 1) + 1 \implies \\
& g(n + x, h + 1) \ge g(x, h + 1) + 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$

Note $g(n, h + 1) + g(x, h + 1) + 1 \lt p$ because it can't require a carry since index $h$ is where the highest index of any carry comes from. Also, \eqref{eq13A} shows there's an integer in $[x + 1, x + n]$ where the coefficient at index $h + 1$ increases by $1$ to $g(n + x, h + 1)$, so all lower coefficients then are $0$, i.e., there's a $1 \le i \le n$ where

$$g(n + i, j) = 0 \; \forall \; 0 \le j \le h \implies \nu_p(n + i) \ge h + 1 \tag{14}\label{eq14A}$$

Using \eqref{eq7A}, this means

$$\nu_p(n + i) \le f \implies h + 1 \le f \tag{15}\label{eq15A}$$

The carries occurred only in the digits with indices between $d$ and $h$, inclusive, so the number of carries, i.e., $e$ (as Kummer's theorem mentioned earlier shows), is less or equal to the number of indices in that range. This gives

$$e \le h - d + 1 \implies d + e \le h + 1 \tag{16}\label{eq16A}$$

Putting \eqref{eq15A} and \eqref{eq16A} together gives \eqref{eq8A}.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many counterexamples.

If $n=2$, then we get, for any $x$,
$$f_2(x)=\frac{(x+2)!}{(x!)\text{lcm}(x+1,  x+2)}=\frac{(x+2)!}{(x!)(x+1)(x+2)}=1\color{red}=(2-1)!$$

If $n=3$ and $x=2^k-1$ where $k$ is a positive integer, then since $$\text{lcm}(x+1,x+2,x+3)=2^{k-1}(x+2)(x+3)$$
we get
$$f_3(2^k-1)=\frac{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}{\text{lcm}(x+1, x+2, x+3)}=\frac{2^k}{2^{k-1}}=2\color{red}=(3-1)!$$

Comment: Thanks for the counter examples!  In each case $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^i}-1\right\rfloor = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor\dfrac{n-1}{p^i}\right\rfloor$. Have you found any counter examples where this formula is wrong?  I am wondering if changing $<$ to $\le$ addresses the counter examples.

Comment: @Larry Freeman : Sorry for the late reply. No, I haven't. Have you proven $f_n(x)\color{red}{\le} (n-1)!$ in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689109/are-these-well-known-properties-of-binomial-coefficients)?