# Are these well known properties of binomial coefficients?

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, solution-verification, factorial, gcd-and-lcm

I apologize for the number of definitions.  I did not know how to state these ideas any simpler.  If anyone can help me simplify the definitions, I will be glad to shorten the details.

Let:

- $x,n$ be integers with $n > 1$ and $x \ge 2n$
- $f(x,n) = \dfrac{(x+n)!}{x!}$
- lcm$(a,b)$ be the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of $a$ and $b$.
- $v_p(x) = $ the maximum power of $p$ that divides $x$ so that $p^{v_p(x)} | x$ but $p^{v_p(x)+1} \nmid x$
- $g(x,n) = \prod\limits_{p\text{ prime & }p \le n} \dfrac{p^{v_p(\text{lcm}(x+1, \dots, x+n))}}{p^{v_p(\text{lcm}(2,3,\dots,n))}}$
- $h(x,n) = \prod\limits_{p\text{ prime &}p > n\text{ & }p^t | f(x,n)}p$
- $t = \dfrac{n!}{\text{lcm}(2,3,\dots,n)}$
- $u = \dfrac{f(x,n)}{\text{lcm}(x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n)}$
- $w = \dfrac{u}{t}$

Does it now follow that the following relations hold for binomial coefficients:

- lcm$(x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n) = g(x,n)h(x,n)\text{lcm}(2,3,\dots,n)$
- ${{x+n} \choose n} = g(x,n)h(x,n)w$
- From the [Sylvester-Schur theorem](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf), $h(x,n) > n$
- $w \le \dfrac{(n-1)!}{t}$  [I am still working on the argument.]
- lcm$(x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n) \le {{x+n}\choose{n}}$lcm$(2,3,\dots,n)$

For me, the most surprising result is that $g(x,n)h(x,n)$ always seem to divide ${{x+n}\choose{n}}$.

Are these well known properties of the binomial coefficient?  Am I wrong in my analysis?  Can anyone find a counter example that shows my observations are wrong?

---

**Edit**:

Fixed a mistake so that ${x \choose n}$ is now ${{x+n}\choose n}$.  Thanks to Collag3n for catching that.

Added 1 more property:

$$\text{lcm}(x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n) \le {{x+n}\choose{n}}\text{lcm}(2,3,\dots,n)$$

**Edit 2**:

It looks like I had not properly defined $g(x,n)$.

I had written $g(x,n) = \prod\limits_{p\text{ prime & }p \le n \text{ & }p^{v_p(n!)} | f(x,n)} \dfrac{p^{v_p(f(x,n))}}{p^{v_p(n!)}}$ but it should be this:

$$g(x,n) = \prod\limits_{p\text{ prime & }p \le n}\dfrac{p^{v_p(\text{lcm}(x+1, \dots, x+n))}}{p^{v_p(\text{lcm}(2,3,\dots,n))}}$$

I also updated my definition of $v_p(x)$ to accommodate the modified definition of $g(x,n)$.

A big thanks to Collag3n for noticing that the previous definition did not work.

**Edit 3**:

My definition for $h(x,n)$ was also not properly defined.

I had written $h(x,n) = \prod\limits_{p\text{ prime &}p > n\text{ & }p | f(x,n)}p$ but it should be:

$$h(x,n) = \prod\limits_{p\text{ prime &}p > n\text{ & }p^t | f(x,n)}p$$

For example, $h(47,6) = 49*17*13*53 = 573,937$.

Comment: do you mean: lcm$(x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n)w = g(x,n)h(x,n)\text{lcm}(2,3,\dots,n)$, and ${x+n \choose n} = g(x,n)h(x,n)$ ?

Comment: Yes, the second one is wrong.  Thanks.  I'll make the corrections!  :-)  For the first one, I believe that represents my thinking.  Do you have a counter example?

Comment: since $n!|f(x,n)$, the condition $p\leq n$ is enough for the product of prime for $g(x,n)$ which then is the prime factorization of ${{x+n} \choose n}$ limited to the $p\leq n$. Now $h(x,n)$ is nearly the prime factorization of ${{x+n} \choose n}$ for $p>n$, so the product of the 2 would give you ${{x+n} \choose n}$, since any prime $p>n$ dividing $f(x,n)$ also divide $\frac{f(x,n)}{n!}={{x+n} \choose n}$. Now prime powers for these $p>n$ are not counted correctly if there is any in the range of $f(x,n)$, so sometimes ${x+n \choose n} = g(x,n)h(x,n)$ (but $w\neq 1$), sometimes not.

Comment: But when it's not, $w$ doesn't seems to compensate.....I tried with (x,n)=(35,12) where no $p>12$ powers appears in $f$ and (527,21) where $23^2$ appears in $f$

Comment: I am not able to follow all of your points.  For example, $g(x,n)$ is only the prime factorization for $p \le n$ when $w=1$.  $\dfrac{(n-1)!}{t}$ can get quite large.  Keeping it small, if you check $n=3$, it is clear that $w=1$ or $w=2$ since $t=\dfrac{3!}{\text{lcm}(2,3)} =1$ and $\dfrac{(3-1)!}{1}=2$  As far as $f(35,12)$, I will write a java app to test it out.  Thanks for the example to try out!  :-)

Comment: Well, the reasoning is $f(x,n)=n!\cdot {{x+n} \choose n}$, it means all $p\leq n$ divides $f(x,n)$, and it does at least up to $p^{v_p(n!)}$, so that last condition does not filter out any of them. And since you take $p^i||\frac{f(x,n)}{n!}={{x+n} \choose n}$ the maximum power of all those $p\leq n$ dividing ${{x+n} \choose n}$...that's how I read the condition on the product of $g(x,n)$. Is it not?

Comment: and for the square (or cube...) case, you can pick $f(47,6)$ where $7^2$ will appear in $f$ (or any $n<p<x<p^2<x+n$)

Comment: For $f(47,6)$, everything seems to add up.  lcm(48,49,50,51,52,53) = 68,872,440, h(x,n)=573,937, g(x,n) = 10, w = 4, ${{47+6}\choose{6}} = 22,957,480 = 10*573937*4$  Is there something that I am missing for your example at $f(47,6)$?

Comment: For $f(35,12)$ everything seems to add up.  lcm(36,...,42) = 482,802,943,863,240.  h(35,12)=17,417,133,617.  g(35,12) = 1, w = 3, ${{35+12}\choose{12}} = 52,251,400,851 = 17417133617*1*3$.  I am not clear what is the problem that you are identifying.  In these two examples, the numbers all add up as far as I can tell.

Comment: I will hold off on $f(527,21)$ unless you feel that this will be different than the other 2 examples.  I suspect that perhaps my definition of each term was not clear.  Hopefully, the examples provided address your concerns.  :-)  If not, just let me know.

Comment: for $(35,12)$ I have $g(x,n)=3$. It is because for $3$, I get $3^5$ in the factorization of $12!$ and $3^6$ in the factorization of $f(x,n)$. Not what you have ?

Comment: Also for $(47,6)$ I have $h(x,n)=81991$ and not 573,937. This is because in your formula, you multiply the different $p$ without any exponent, which should give a square-free value.

Comment: You know. In looking over my definition, I believe that I misdefined (,). So, you are right in your confusion. Apologies. I had meant to say (+1,+2,…,+) instead of (,). I will update my definition. Very sorry for that. Thank you so much for your patience!   My previous calculations were based on the updated definition of $g(x,n)$.  I believe that it should now add up.

Comment: :) I'll check that later. I am still confused by $h(x,n)$. Isn't it square-free by definition ? because 573,937 is not

Comment: You are right.  I did not properly define $h(x,n)$.  In my calculations: $h(47,6) = 49*17*13*53=573,937$.  I will update my definition.

Comment: Well, I would say $g$ is prime factorization of $l=\frac{\text{lcm}(x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n)}{\text{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots,n)}$ limited to $p\leq n$, and $h$ is the prime factorization of ${{x+n} \choose n}=\frac{(x+1)(x+2)\dots(x+n)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\dots\cdot n}$ for $p>n$, which is equivalent to the factorisation of $l=\frac{\text{lcm}(x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n)}{\text{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots,n)}$ for $p>n$ since $p$ appears in only one of the terms of $f(x,n)$ and not in the denominator. So we have indeed $g\cdot h=l$. And since $w=\frac{{x+n} \choose n}{l}$...

Comment: Great analysis!  Very clear.  Thanks very much for thinking it through!